# Finding the source code of livestreams

Tags: html

So in my country, the official way to watch sports are by paying the company some money to provide us some sports channels. But they are extremely overpriced here. Compared to the avarage salaries, it costs around 120 dollars per month for only (!) tv channels. So internet and phone is not included.

Most of us try and finds alternatives. There are websites online who stream those channels for free. But i'd like them on my tv. I tried finding their source link, so I could play it on SimpleTv, but the links become inactive/don't work after a few hours. So I constantly have to renew them again. I find the source of the video by pressing F12 (in Chrome) and checking out the stream links there.

The reason i'm asking this, is because I have other streams, I've found online, that do work all the time without me needing to change them.

To sum it all up, here comes the million dollar question; can I somehow find a static livestream link? If so how?

Here's the url to the livestreams btw; https://ajanspor2.tv/izle/ligtv

Comment: This question is off topic as it is not a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

Well probably not, but you could maybe code a tiny program (maybe in php) that searches for the current link and automatically redirects to it. This would work

Comment: How do I do that ? :p

Comment: You have to ask yourself how you as a human would identify the links. What do they have in common? Maybe the code in front is always the same? Then you can translate this to any language you want.